# AWS Lambda with Python 2.7 Error

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-lambda

I'm using AWS Lambda to turn on\off EC2 instances at a specified intervals vai CloudWatch. I write AWS Lambda code using Python 2.7 runtime and put the code:

```
import boto3

region = 'xxxxxx'

instances = ['i-xxxxxxxxxx']

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    ec2 = boto3.client('ec2', region_name=region)
    ec2.stop_instances(InstanceIds=instances)
    print 'stopped your instances: ' + str(instances)
```

As the inline code. But I want to test the stopping of EC2 instance by manually trigger the lambda function where I get the following error in the execution log:

```
{
  "errorMessage": "Handler 'handler' missing on module 'index'"
}
```

Anyone help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to rename `lambda_handler` to `handler` in your python script. OR tell Lambda to look for the handler of `lambda_handler` instead of the default `handler`. It is trying to execute a handler that does exist in your script and that’s why it’s erroring.

Also, you should add a `return` to the bottom of your function.